# Python code to use a regular expression to make sure a string is alphanumeric plus . - _

Tags: python, regex, alphanumeric

I looked and searched and couldn't find what I needed although I think it should be simple (if you have any Python experience, which I don't).

Given a string, I want to verify, in Python, that it contains ONLY alphanumeric characters: `a-zA-Z0-9` and `.` `_` `-`

examples:

Accepted:

`bill-gates`

`Steve_Jobs`

`Micro.soft`

Rejected:

`Bill gates` -- no spaces allowed

`me@host.com` -- @ is not alphanumeric

I'm trying to use:

`if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$", username) == True:`

But that doesn't seem to do the job...

Comment: re.match() doesn't return a boolean, it returns a [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match), which "always has a boolean value True", or None.

Comment: It is always bad to use `== True`. It is at best redundant and in a case like this, just does not work.

Comment: Do you really consider (for example) `---.___` to be a valid match?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) does not return a boolean; it returns a `MatchObject` on a match,  or `None` on a non-match.

```
>>> re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$", "hello")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7600250>
>>> re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$", "    ")
>>> print re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$", "    ")
None
```

So, you shouldn't do `re.match(...) == True`; rather, you should be checking `re.match(...) is not None` in this case, which can be further shortened to just `if re.match(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

Never use `== True` or `== False` in a comparison. Many types already have a bool equivalent which you should use instead:

```
if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$", username):
```

Answer (score 2):

Could also shorten it slightly to :

```
if re.match(r'^[\w.-]+$', username):
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider this for a valid username:
**1) Username must be 6-30 characters long**
**2) Username may only contain:**

- Uppercase and lowercase letters
- Numbers from 0-9 and
- Special characters _ - .

**3) Username may not:**

- Begin or finish with characters _ - .
- Have more than one sequential character _ - . inside

This would be example of usage:
`if re.match(r'^(?![-._])(?!.*[_.-]{2})[\w.-]{6,30}(?<![-._])$',username) is not None:`

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use many regular expressions you can compile it for speed (or readability)

```
import re 
ALPHANUM=re.compile('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$')

for u in users:
    if ALPHANUM.match(u) is None:
        print "invalid"
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to `re.match()`, `re.search()` or `re.compile()` are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I do my validation this way in my utils class:

```
def valid_re(self, s, r):
 reg = re.compile(r)
 return reg.match(s)
```

Then I call the utils instance, and check this way:

```
if not utils.valid_re(username, r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$'):
        error = "Invalid username!"
```